# Why my score counter won't add properly?

Tags: jquery, function

I can't get this score to add properly. I want it to add one point every time an answer with the class of .CA is selected. Here is the code:

```
var quiz = function () {
    total = 0;
    $('#submit').click(function () {

        var score = function () {
            var answer = $(':input').has('.CA');
            var thischecked = answer.is(':checked');
            if (thischecked) {
                total++;
                $('#points').text('Score: ' + total);
            } else {
                $('#points').text('Score: ' + total);
            }
        };

        var currentquestion = $('.activequestion');
        var nextquestion = currentquestion.next();

        currentquestion.fadeOut(0).removeClass('activequestion');

        nextquestion.fadeIn(0).addClass('activequestion');

        score();

    });
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks in advance. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0wu6z1e/10/) if needed.

Comment: Note that `has()` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object. This means that `answer.is(':checked')` will be throwing a syntax error. Check the console for other errors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where looking for a child `.CA` inside your input elements, which will never be true, if you change as follows:

```
var answer = $(':input.CA');
if (answer.is(':checked')) {
```

The evaluation will work as you need, because you select the input that has class `.CA` and then check if its `checked` or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/h0wu6z1e/13/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your `<input>` elements don't *have* a child element with class '.CA', so `has('.CA')` is always false. To correct: `var answer = $(':input.CA');` which means an `<input>` element with a class '.CA'.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0wu6z1e/12/)